# Update a qsys2 view db2 as400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Can we update the view qsys2.SCHEDULED_JOB_INFO with sql? I want to create a program that automatise
scheduling job with a given date

Comment: you cannot update system views directly. Instead, to create a scheduled job, you use one of the documented methods , and on success, the details of the new job (and related metadata) will be populated in system views.

Comment: @mao Your comment looks very much like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

use the `GO CMDSCDE` command to get a list of all the commands that work with the job scheduler.